# FreeBSD Ngnix installation error

Tags: nginx, freebsd

I have a VPS which has Apache webserver installed.

I'm trying to install Ngnix on it since my new server will be needing to handle large amount of connection simultaneously. I used [this install guide](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=4422) and did:

```
cd  /usr/ports/www/nginx
make install clean
```

However I get this error:

```
adding module in /usr/ports/www/nginx/work/arut-nginx-dav-ext-module-0e07a3e
./configure: error: no /usr/ports/www/nginx/work/arut-nginx-dav-ext-module-0e07a3e/config was found
===>  Script "configure" failed unexpectedly.
```

I'm pretty new to FreeBSD and I am used to controlling my server using Direct Admin.

What shall I do next ?

Comment: Which install guide did you follow? Can't you use any prebuilt / binary packages?

Comment: @Pothi i've added to my question the installation guide i used.. i don't really know how to answer your question.. i did previously installed packages from ports on the FreeBsd.. was that what you mean ?

Comment: `What shell i do next ?` **BASH** ... SCNR :)

Comment: btw, what are your configure-options? i see you use dav which must be enabled manually. are you sure you have `arut-nginx-dav-ext-module` available?

Comment: I've actually manually removed all the configure options that caused errors and now i remain with: error: the HTTP image filter module requires the GD library. trying to understand how to install the gd library :)

Comment: @AsafNevo There are pre-built binaries available for FreeBSD. If you run `pkg_add -r nginx` it will automatically install the binaries without building them locally.

Comment: @thatguyfromoverthere 1. Bash isn't installed by default in FreeBSD. 2. He's not passing configure-options manually, he's using FreeBSD's automated ports system. It's not like anything in Linux that I'm aware of.

Comment: Well, there is ---one little village--- on linux-distribution which uses a sort of ports. See [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portage_%28software%29). :-)  As for FreeBSD, The lines which come after the part which the OP posted usually contain just what do to.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that your ports tree is up to date. If you haven't used portsnap before then run `portsnap fetch ; portsnap extract`. If you have used it before, then use `portsnap fetch ; portsnap update`. If you're not sure, run the first one.

1. Now in `/usr/ports/www/nginx`, run `make config`.
2. For the first build attempt, untick the `HTTP_DAV_EXT` and select OK. This is just temporary to make sure that everything else is working.
3. Now run `make` which should compile.
4. When this is completed, re-run `make config`, re-select `HTTP_DAV_EXT` and run `make clean ; make`.
5. Once this builds then you can run `make install` which will have everything installed for you.

If you don't need DAV (which you might not), after step 3, just run `make install clean`.